# Possible to use omnibox in Google Chrome Web Application?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to add the possibility to a simple Chrome web app, to use the Chrome Omnibox. The app should just be an icon on the start-page of chrome and add Omnibox functionality.

Adding the attribute `"omnibox": { "keyword" : "x" }` to my manifest.json brings up the message

> Feature 'omnibox' is not accessible. Not allowed for specified package type (theme, app, etc.).

Is it possible to enable this functionality or can I develop an extension which behaves exactly like an Chrome web app, so I could use the omnibox inside that extension?

Thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 0):

If you're making a [Hosted App](https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/developers_guide), you are very limited in what you can access.  I believe a Hosted App can only perform actions that a normal HTML5 web page could (with a few narrow exceptions, like long-running [background pages](https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/background)).  If you want to include omnibox functionality, you'll have to make it a Packaged App -- but it could be a Packaged App that opens your web page like your current app *and* includes omnibox support, since the functionality of Packaged Apps is a superset of Hosted Apps functionality.